# Espresso withText in TextView Doesn't match selected View

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm running into a odd test failure with Espresso. The following is to test a TextView in a displayed Dialog. I get the following error:

```
   com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with string from resource id: <2131099772>' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with string from resource id: <2131099772>[my_content] value: Test Content Available
Got: "TextView{id=2131296340, res-name=dialog_content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=620, height=38, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Test Content Available, input-type=0, ime-target=false}"

at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:579)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:69)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:40)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:159)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:133)
at com.myapp.testContentDetails(FPATest.java:109)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:167)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 'with string from resource id: <2131099772>' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with string from resource id: <2131099772>[my_content] value: Test Content Available
Got: "TextView{id=2131296340, res-name=dialog_content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=620, height=38, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Test Content Available, input-type=0, ime-target=false}"

at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat(ViewMatchers.java:789)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions$2.check(ViewAssertions.java:76)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.run(ViewInteraction.java:145)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So clearly, the view is found, and in it's details, you can see text= the value I'm expecting. Yet it says doesn't match. It's run with the following test statement

```
onView(withId(R.id.dialog_content)).check(
                matches(withText(R.string.my_content)));
```

I tried doing it with the following statement as well, but got a NoMatchingViewException, even through the View shows in the view hierarchy of the exception.

```
onView(withText(R.string.my_content)).check(
                matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Any help on why this would fail? Its worth noting i'm able to withText() isDisplayed() on a sibling field in the dialog.

Comment: The built-in withText(int resourceId) that comes with Espresso is buggy. It only works if the text being checked is a java.lang.String, but a lot of texts being used are other subclasses of CharSequence, like Editable or Spannable. Make sure the type of text you are comapring with is actually String, and if not write your own matcher that matches the String content without looking at the type.

Comment: @haffax Perfect! I had set the text in the TextView with an Html.fromHtml(), which of course resulted in a Spanned object. Wrote a custom matcher that just did a #toString() on the textView.getText() in the #matchesSafely() and it works perfectly. If you want to submit this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted, thanks!

Comment: In my case, I was matching against all-caps text that was on screen. The real string was lowercase with allCaps property set, so I had to match against lowercase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer was created based on @haffax's comment above.

```
/**
 * Original source from Espresso library, modified to handle spanned fields
 * 
 * Returns a matcher that matches a descendant of {@link TextView} that is
 * displaying the string associated with the given resource id.
 * 
 * @param resourceId
 *            the string resource the text view is expected to hold.
 */
public static Matcher<View> withText(final int resourceId) {

    return new BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView.class) {
        private String resourceName = null;
        private String expectedText = null;

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with string from resource id: ");
            description.appendValue(resourceId);
            if (null != this.resourceName) {
                description.appendText("[");
                description.appendText(this.resourceName);
                description.appendText("]");
            }
            if (null != this.expectedText) {
                description.appendText(" value: ");
                description.appendText(this.expectedText);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(TextView textView) {
            if (null == this.expectedText) {
                try {
                    this.expectedText = textView.getResources().getString(
                            resourceId);
                    this.resourceName = textView.getResources()
                            .getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
                } catch (Resources.NotFoundException ignored) {
                    /*
                     * view could be from a context unaware of the resource
                     * id.
                     */
                }
            }
            if (null != this.expectedText) {
                return this.expectedText.equals(textView.getText()
                        .toString());
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote it twice